# Showing that $\mu(\limsup_{n\to\infty}f^{-n}(A)\setminus A) = 0$ if $\mu(A)=\mu(f^{-1}(A)),\mu(A\setminus f^{-1}(A))=0$ and $\mu$ is finite

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, limsup-and-liminf, measurable-functions

Let $\mu$ be a probability measure over $X$, $f:X\to X$ a $\mu$ measurable mapping and suppose that $\mu$ preserves $f$ in the sense that $\forall S\subset X:\mu(S) = \mu(f^{-1}(S))$. Let $A\subset X$ a $\mu$ measurable set such that $\mu(A\setminus f^{-1}(A)) = 0$ and define $B=\limsup_{n\to\infty}f^{-n}(A) = \bigcap_{n=0}^\infty \bigcup_{k\geq n}f^{-k}(A)$. Then $f^{-1}(B) = B$.

I am trying to show that $\mu(B\setminus A) = 0$ but I don't know how to connect the assumption $\mu(A\setminus f^{-1}(A)) = 0$ back to $\mu(B\setminus A)$. Namely, by invariance of $\mu$ and $B$, we can take as high pre-image as we want in the sense that $\mu(B\setminus A) = \mu(B\setminus f^{-N}(A)),\forall N\in\mathbb{N}$. Therefore we can remove any single $f^{-k}(A)$ in the limsup $\bigcap_{n=0}^\infty \bigcup_{k\geq n}f^{-k}(A)$. But this is a finite, single-time, approach to an asymptotic object and I don't see how you could remove all the $f^{-k}(A)$s (or just enough of them) to make $\mu(B\setminus A) = 0$. Something to consider is that for any $N\in\mathbb{N}$, $f^{-N}(A)\setminus A \subset \bigcup_{n=0}^{N-1}f^{-n-1}(A)\setminus f^{-n}(A) = \bigcup_{n=0}^{N-1}f^{-n}(f^{-1}(A)\setminus A)$. But I am not sure how to use this superset to my advantage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints: Verify that $$f^{-n}(A)\setminus A\subseteq \bigcup_k [f^{-k}(A)\setminus f^{-(k-1)}(A)\setminus]$$ by observing that $f^{n}(x) \in A$ and $x \notin A$ implies that there is  smallest $k$ such that $f^{k}(x) \in A$]. Next use the hypothesis to see that $\mu ([f^{-k}(A)\setminus f^{-(k-1)}(A)])=0$ for each $k$. It follows that $\mu (\bigcup_n f^{-n}(A)\setminus A)=0$.

[Lemma

$\mu(C)=\mu(D)$ and $\mu (C\setminus D)=0$ implies that $\mu (D\setminus C)=0$

Proof: $\mu(C\cap D)+\mu (C\setminus D)=\mu(C\cap D)+\mu (D\setminus C)$. Cancel the first term.

Corollary

$\mu (f^{-1}(A)\setminus A)=0$

$\mu (f^{-1}(S))=\mu(S)$ for any $S$. Iteration gives $\mu (f^{-j}(S))=\mu (S)$ for any $j$ for any $S$. Also, $\mu (f^{-1}(A)\setminus A)=0$ so $\mu (f^{-j}(A)\setminus f^{-(j-1)}(A))=\mu (f^{-(j-1)} (f^{-1}(A)\setminus A)]=0$ for any $j$ ].

Comment: Could you walk me through how $\mu\left(f^{-k}(A)\setminus f^{-(k-1)}(A)\right)=\mu\left(f^{-k}(A)\setminus f^{-k + 1}(A)\right)=0$ follows from the hypothesis for $k\geq 0$? We can certainly take as many pre-images as we like to get $\mu\left(f^{-k}(A)\setminus f^{-(k-1)}(A)\right)=\mu\left(f^{-k-N}(A)\setminus f^{-k + 1-N}(A)\right)$ for any $N=0,1,2,\dots$. But what we need is $-k - N = 0, -k + 1 - N = -1$, which is impossible.

Comment: I have added some details.  @EpsilonAway

Comment: I still don't understand why $f^{-j}(A)\setminus f^{-(j-1)}(A) = f^{-j}(A\setminus f^{-1}(A))$. To be precise, we know that the preimage commutes with usual set operations, hence we can factor a preimage out of $f^{-j}(A)\setminus f^{-(j-1)}(A)$. If we factor $f^{-j}$ we get $f^{-j}(A)\setminus f^{-(j-1)}(A) = f^{-j}(A\setminus f^1(A))$.

If we then jump into $\mu$, by invariance regarding $f$ we can then get rid of $f^{-j}$. But then we are left with $\mu(A\setminus f^1(A))$. And I don't see how to massage the $+1$ iteration of $f$ to a $-1$.

Comment: @EpsilonAway The argument should now be very clear.